# How to stream data written to file to stdout

Tags: python, file, file-descriptor

I have shared library implemented in C which provides a function `F`. Every time I call `F` it logs its output in the file `error.log`.

Now I'm trying to capture the output produced by `F` from a python script (I'm using python 2.7.5 which I can't change for reasons out of my control).

I would like to stream the data written into `error.log` to a different file or `stdout`. I can't just open the file and parse it because it has more of stuff logged in, including the output of previous and later runs of `F`. I'm only interested in a specific execution which I can't be able to recognize from just the logging. That's why I'm trying to capture the output instead.

I tried opening `error.log` from python and then changing the file descriptor to make it point to `stdout`, but that doesn't seem to work (I tried the same with `stdout` and `stderr` and it did work).

What I'm doing is roughly

```
with open('error.log') as logfile:
    with redirect_output(logfile, sys.stdout):
        function_implemented_in_C()
```

where `redirect_output` is a context manager I implemented to do the redirection:

```
@contextmanager
def redirect_output(orig, dest):
    orig_fd = orig.fileno()
    with os.fdopen(os.dup(orig_fd)) as old_orig_fd:
        os.dup2(dest.fileno(), orig_fd)
    
    try:
        yield orig
    finally:
        # clean and restore fd's
```

I can't get this to work. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**

I reduced the problem to a simple script and it still doesn't seem to work. I guess it has something to do with the data being generated from a function in a shared lib (?) because if I do the same but redirecting the `write` calls from a file opened from python it works. This example works fine:

```
import sys
import os

def foo():
    f = open('dummy.txt', 'wb', buffering=0)
    os.dup2(sys.stdout.fileno(), f.fileno())
    f.write('some test data\n')
    f.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    foo()
```

But this doesn't

```
import sys
import os

def foo():
    f = open('error.log', 'wb', buffering=0)
    os.dup2(sys.stdout.fileno(), f.fileno())
    function_implemented_in_C()
    f.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    foo()
```

Comment: I dont think you could name a variable `from` in python.

Comment: In my code is different, I just typed it like that here in hopes of making it clearer. I'll update the snippet to avoid confusions.

Comment: I'm a little confused. Are there 2 programs? One that is running C, which is writing to `error.log`, and one that is running python, which reads `error.log`? 

Or is it the same program that is handling both?

Comment: @EhteshChoudhury there's only my script which is in python. From there I load and use some functions which are implemented in C and are available as part of a Shared Library. One function from the shared lib produces some output in a file which I would like to capture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering my own question in case somebody stumble into this question with the same problem.

The issue here is that the C function producing the output in `error.log` launches a different process to perform the task. This makes not possible to easily redirect writes to the file to `stdout`, since the file descriptors are process specific.

So, if your function happens to produce the output using the same process, then the following should work

```
import sys
import os

def foo():
    f = open('dummy.txt', 'wb', buffering=0)
    os.dup2(sys.stdout.fileno(), f.fileno())
    f.write('some test data\n')
    f.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    foo()
```

If that's not the case then you can approach the problem by setting a loop reading from the file so it gets the newly written data. Something like (I haven't tried this code so it could not run):

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Pipe

def foo(filename, pipe_conn):
    with open(filename) as f:
        while True:
            line = f.readline()
            do_something(line)
            if pipe_conn.poll(0.01):
                break

def bar(pipe_conn):
    function_implemented_in_C()
    pipe_conn.send(['done'])
    pipe_conn.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parent_conn, child_conn = Pipe()
    p = Process(target=bar, args=(child_conn,))
    p.start()
    foo(parent_conn)
    p.join()
```